Convert raster (.tif file) to .txt
I am new to Python. I managed to write the code to convert only one raster to .txt format (xyz coordinates) and it works beautifully.
But the problem is that I need a code that will convert multiple rasters (more precisely) 150 of them. Maybe a for loop? I can't seem to write functional code. The rasters are named in order raster1, raster2, ...raster150.
And here is the code. There's probably a faster way for certain parts (but I'm not familiar with it).
import os  
import rasterio  
import numpy as np  
from rasterio.transform import Affine  
from affine import Affine

#Filepath   
dataset = '/home/Radna površina/DEMovi/raster1.tif' 
              
#Outfile path         
outpath = '/home/Radna površina/DEMovi/tiff_to_txt' 
  
#Open multiband raster        
raster = rasterio.open(dataset)  
T0 = raster.transform  
dem = raster.read()   

#All rows and columns    
cols, rows = np.meshgrid(np.arange(dem.shape[2]), np.arange(dem.shape[1]))   

#Get affine transform for pixel centres      
T1 = T0 * Affine.translation(0.5, 0.5)  

#Function to convert pixel row/column index (from 0) to easting/northing at centre  
rc2xy = lambda r, c: T1 * (c, r)  
   
print(rc2xy(0, 1))   
 
#All eastings and northings     
eastings, northings = np.vectorize(rc2xy, otypes=[float, float])(rows, cols)
     
#skip NaN values    
dem = dem[0, ...]   
x = eastings[dem != -9999]    
y = northings[dem != -9999]       
z = dem[dem != -9999]   
   
d = np.stack((x, y, z)).T    
del x, y, z, dem    
np.savetxt(os.path.join(outpath, os.path.basename(dataset) + '.txt'), d)


When you say you, "can't seem to write functional code" - what makes you say that? Are  you getting an error? Does it take too long to run, or seem to get stuck running? If your code works for a single raster, try to turn that into a function that takes input and output files as parameters. Then you can build a loop that loops through all the raster files and runs your convert raster function once per raster file.

will do, thank you very much
